# NpgsqlCommand returns -1 in affected rows

Tags: c#, postgresql, boolean, sqlcommand

I'm trying to make a bool out of this, to check if param accountname exist in our database. The variable doesAccountExist always returns -1 for both true and false, expecting 1 or 0.

This is not a sproc, I read that people had problems with this using sprocs.

If I run the SQLCommand in pgadmin, it works. I see a row that is 1 or 0 depending if it exists or not.

I've been using an admin account for this to see if it was my read-only account that was the problem, sadly it wasn't.

```
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;";
        NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);

        string commandString = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '"+accountname+"') THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END";
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(commandString, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int doesAccountExist = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

            if (doesAccountExist == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            connection.Close();
            return false;           
        }
```

EDIT:

A solution probably. Since ozczecho enlightened me that ExecuteNonQuery() only return rows for UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT I changed to ExecuteScalar() and converted the object to a bool.

bool doesAccountExist = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScalar());

It's a solution, it works, I get true or false in return.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery - Returns the number of rows affected (for insert/update/delete)..-1 for everything else..see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx